# Audio and video solution with “whisper” support

Tags: tools, online-roleplaying

For our online gaming sessions we use Fantasy Grounds as our virtual table top. We’ve also tried a number of other solutions that work to a certain extent but without fully support all our needs which are as follow:

1. Voice and video.
2. Ability to stream my own music from iTunes
3. Ability to speak (whisper) only to one of the players.
4. Good audio quality.

So far, we’ve tried:

1. Discord + Voicemeeter: no whisper, bad music quality. Excellent video and voice.
2. Ts + Voicemeeter. No whisper, no video. Excellent music and voice quality.
3. Roll20. Bad experience, only preuploaded music. Normal video and audio and whisper support.

Currently we are using Roll20 + Ts + Voicemeeter. This meets all the requirements but is a complicated setup, with normal audio and video quality.

**Note:** The reason for whisper functionality is that, occasionally, group will split and they’ll see and hear different things... sometimes the player themselves prefer other players not to know what exactly has happened.

**How can I use these tools to make the setup simpler, and improve audio/video quality?**

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question, but this also seems like a shopping question.

Comment: Can you confirm if you are asking about finding a tool to resolve this? If so, unfortunately, [asking for tool recommendations are off-topic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5881/are-tool-recommendation-questions-on-topic).

Comment: I’m looking for tools but the question is, I think, presented in the recommended way, that is, present the problem I have and asking for ways to solve it. I have 4 main requirements given this is online play it can only be solved by technology but I’m willing to accept any problem that allows me to do 4 points.

Comment: As per the attached meta discussion: “The trick is to do as ... ask a question about your problem a be willing to accept a variety of answers, technique, tool, etc to solve your problem”. I agree it’s likely to elicit tool responses so maybe offtopic. I also think however that is a particularly common set of requirements for online play. Feel free to vote for close though as I’d say it’s borderline

Comment: @JorgeCórdoba You can reword your question to be a non-tool recommendation question by saying "I am using Discord + Voicemeeter, how can I whisper and improve music quality while retaining good video and voice quality" and accepted frame challenges in the form "You should try use tool X instead".

Comment: I made an edit that should remove the problem. Feel free to reword, but focus on "I have X problem and am using Y tools, how can I solve it"

Comment: @pwi I'm not sure if rewording so you can get a tool rec is an acceptable way to circumvent the closure.

Comment: @NautArch Closures are not permanent. The problem with the question was that it was a tools rec. It has been edited is no longer a tools rec, so please do not hold a grudge against it :) This is the way that closing questions is supposed to work.

Comment: @JorgeCórdoba how important is the streaming music requirement?  Could it be dropped?

Comment: @GcL it’s a nice to have if possible. That was the main reason we thought roll20 was not adequate (together with the fact is not as nice as discord in terms of audio quality)

Answer (score 3):

So I participate in a couple of games that are run online, and we have quite similar requirements to what you have(though we do not have a video requirement). What we do is -

- We use Roll20 for the ease of showing maps, making rolls both public and private as well as some quick gm whispers as well as allow for some ambient background music. (We do not use its voice and video chat in any manner)
- Use a discord server for our voice chats. This allows the party to split-up for a short duration where the GM can hop between two(or more) channels depending on how the party split up and deal with them individually without one group knowing whats happening to the other. This also allows us to use a simple bot to play music/soundbites as needed. (We also use a bot to record our sessions in case the gm or players want to go over the recordings to brush up on what happened or to confirm any hunches they get later on)

This has been working for us for over 2 years now and I believe that discord supports video as well, so this setup should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Use Discord. It has everything you need already.

Create a server with two or more voice rooms, and swap between them as needed for the scenes. You can put a limit on how many people can access each room or set permissions for each one to control who can enter where, too.

[image]

Using Discord, you can also selectively mute or deafen people as needed, by right-clicking their names:

[image]

Lastly, but not least, use [Rythm](https://rythmbot.co/) instead of Voicemeeter for your music. While it can't be attached to iTunes, you *can* plug it on any non-private video on YouTube, which simplifies a lot of things. If you want to use your own music without making it public, you can upload the tracks to an unlisted video and feed the URLs to Rythm for it to play.

Comment: To whisper to an individual in a group of 4, you'd have to mute and deafen the other three?  Is there a shortcut for "mute & deafen" everybody else?

Comment: @GcL You can always send a private (text) message to the other person, or move with that person to a separate text channel. Deafening the other three is also an option.

Comment: Given the actual rate the group split happens, deafening the other three is a good enough workaround for me, I wasn't aware that could be done.

I'm testing this and, if it works, I'll mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: Rhythm is shutting down. But there are other bots out there that can play music from Youtube.